# Load Static Content with CherryPy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I tried now many things and I googled for hours but I couldn't solve my problem.

Config File:

```
[/] 
tools.staticdir.root = "/Users/phil/Dropbox/Projects/AppName" 

[/main.css] 
tools.staticfile.on = True 
tools.staticfile.filename = "/Users/phil/Dropbox/Projects/AppName/css/main.css" 

[/images] 
tools.staticdir.on = True 
tools.staticdir.dir = "images"
```

CherryPy Code:

```
import cherrypy, os
class AppName(object):
def index(self):
    return "<img src='images/logo.jpeg'>"
index.exposed = True

cherrypy.config.update('/Users/phil/Dropbox/Projects/AppName/conf/AppName.config')
cherrypy.quickstart(AppName())
```

My problem is that it doesn't work, I tried everything with combining paths and so on but the image and the css won't load when I do sth like return '"

Here is the error I get when loading my Application:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2012:22:28:47] "GET /images/logo.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 1268 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5"
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to add some details about what behavior you are actually seeing.  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: "My problem is that it doesnt work" is not a very helpful summary of the problem. You should post some code, and the errors you get.

Comment: edited with all the code and errors

Comment: What permissions does logo.jpeg have?

Comment: 644. But if i write the html in a normal html file and open it it works :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what the Problem was, but this works:

```
[/]
tools.staticdir.root = "/Users/phil/Dropbox/Projects/AppName"

[/images]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "images"
```

Start App with:

```
cherrypy.quickstart(AppName(), '/', 'AppName.config')
```

CherryPy Code:

```
def index(self):
    return "<img src='/images/logo.jpeg'>"
index.exposed = True
```

I think the / before the images is also important. Thanks to all

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [Serving Static Content](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/files/static.html#forming-urls) section of the Cherrypy manual, and see if that can help you out.

Alternatively, here's what I've used to deliver static content before - a dictionary inside of `main()`.

```
conf = {
        '/':
        {'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))},
          '/css': {
          'tools.staticfile.on': True,
          'tools.staticfile.filename': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'css/')
        }
      }
cherrypy.quickstart(AppName(), config=conf)
```

Comment: i tried this but i get the same error. i also read the manual and tried all of it but nothing worked. I tried it now on a Windows Pc with a different file, same error.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your config file:

```
[/]
tools.staticdir.debug: True
log.screen: True
```

You should immediately be able to narrow the problem down.

Comment: If i add this to the config nothing changes. No Log file or Log Output in the Terminal. So i guess there is a problem with loading the config file? ill try to load this direct as a dict

Answer (score 1):

I spend a while getting this to work on Windows so I'm hoping it'll be helpful to share what's (currently) working. I am using `cherrypy.quickstart(website(), '/', "server.conf")` to start the server.

I did find that I had to specify the subfolder in `js` manually.

```
## Server Configuration
[global]
server.socket_port = 3030
#engine.autoreload.on = False  #Might as well turn off when working on HTML
log.error_file = "H:\\My Documents BACKED UP\GitProjects\website\logfile"

[/]
tools.staticdir.debug = True
log.screen = True
tools.sessions.on = True

[/js]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "H:\\My Documents BACKED UP\GitProjects\website\js"

[/js/vendor]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "H:\\My Documents BACKED UP\GitProjects\website\js\\vendor"

[/img]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "H:\\My Documents BACKED UP\GitProjects\website\img"

[/css]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "H:\\My Documents BACKED UP\GitProjects\website\css"
```